# Multiplying two floats doesn't give exact result

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to multiply two `float`s as follows:

```
float number1 = 321.12;
float number2 = 345.34;
float rexsult = number1 * number2;
```

The result I want to see is 110895.582, but when I run the code it just gives me 110896. Most of the time I'm having this issue. Any calculator gives me the exact result with all decimals. How can I achive that result?

edit : It's C code. I'm using XCode iOS simulator.

Comment: Is this C, or Java? It can be either from what you have shown.

Comment: And you should use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just truncating it when you print it? How did you see the value that you get?

Comment: I used double too, same result.

Comment: you simply only printed the result to 6 digits. this is default in C++, but you can change that. In C++, for example, with `std::cout<<std::setprecision(16)<<x;`

Comment: I saw the result in Variables area of XCode IDE. When I printed it with %f, it's showing all decimals.

But
`std::ostringstream stringStream;`
`stringStream << rexsult;`
`char * utf8Bytes = strdup(stringStream.str().c_str());`

here utf8Bytes is rounded too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a lot of rounding going on.

```
float a = 321.12; // this number will be rounded
float b = 345.34; // this number will also be rounded
float r = a * b;  // and this number will be rounded too
printf("%.15f\n", r);
```

I get 110895.578125000000000 after the three separate roundings.

1. If you want more than 6 decimal digits' worth of precision, you will *have* to use `double` and not `float`.  (Note that I said "decimal digits' worth", because you don't get decimal digits, you get binary.)  As it stands, 1/2 ULP of error (a worst-case bound for a *perfectly* rounded result) is about 0.004.
2. If you want exactly rounded decimal numbers, you will have to use a specialized decimal library for such a task.  A `double` has more than enough precision for scientists, but if you work with money everything has to be 100% exact.  No floating point numbers for money.

Unlike integers, floating point numbers take some real work before you can get accustomed to their pitfalls.  See "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)", which is the classic introduction to the topic.

**Edit:** Actually, I'm not sure that the code rounds three times.  It might round *five* times, since the constants for `a` and `b` might be rounded first to double-precision and then to single-precision when they are stored.  But I don't know the rules of this part of C very well.

Comment: “It might round five times” Exactly, but for most decimal numbers, first rounding to `double` and then to `float` is identical to rounding to `float` directly. When I was looking for an innocent-looking decimal number between 1 and 2 with double rounding issues for the purpose of http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz , I had to use 14 digits after the point. I couldn't find any with only 13 digits.

Answer (score 3):

You will never get the exact result that way.

First of all, number1 ≠ 321.12 because that value cannot be represented exactly in a base-2 system. You'll need an infinite number of bits for it.

The same holds for number2 ≠ 345.34.

So, you begin with inexact values to begin with.

Then the product will get rounded because multiplication gives you double the number of significant digits but the product has to be stored in `float` again if you multiply floats.

You probably want to use a 10-based system for your numbers. Or, in case your numbers only have 2 decimal digits of the fractional, you can use integers (32-bit integers are sufficient in this case, but you may end up needing 64-bit):

32112 * 34534 = 1108955808.

That represents 321.12 * 345.34 = 110895.5808.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C you could easily set the precision by using "%.xf" where x is the wanted precision.

For example:

```
float n1 = 321.12;
float n2 = 345.34;
float result = n1 * n2;

printf("%.20f", result);
```

Output:

```
110895.57812500000000000000
```

However, note that `float` only gives six digits of precision. For better precision use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

- floating point variables are only approximate representation, not precise one. Not every number can "fit" into float variable. For example, there is no way to put 1/10 (0.1) into binary variable, just like it's not possible to put 1/3 into decimal one (you can only approximate it with endless 0.33333)
- when outputting such variables, it's usual to apply many rounding options. Unless you set them all, you can never be sure which of them are applied. This is especially true for << operators, as the stream can be told how to round BEFORE <<.

Printf also does some rounding. Consider http://codepad.org/LLweoeHp:

```
float t = 0.1f;
printf("result: %f\n", t);
--
result: 0.100000
```

Well, it looks fine. Why? Because printf defaulted to some precision and rounded up the output. Let's dial in 50 places after decimal point: http://codepad.org/frUPOvcI

```
float t = 0.1f;
printf("result: %.50f\n", t);
--
result: 0.10000000149011611938476562500000000000000000000000
```

That's different, isn't it? After 625 the float ran out of capacity to hold more data, that's why we see zeroes.
A double can hold more digits, but 0.1 in binary is not finite. Double has to give up, eventually: http://codepad.org/RAd7Yu2r

```
double t = 0.1;
printf("result: %.70f\n", t);
--
result: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625000000000000000
```

In your example, 321.12 alone is enough to cause trouble: http://codepad.org/cgw3vUKn

```
float t = 321.12f;
printf("and the result is: %.50f\n", t);
result: 321.11999511718750000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is why one has to round up floating point values before presenting them to humans.

Calculator programs don't use floats or doubles at all. They implement decimal number format. eg:

```
struct decimal
{
     int mantissa; //meaningfull digits
     int exponent; //number of decimal zeroes
};
```

Ofc that requires reinventing all operations: addition, substraction, multiplication and division. Or just look for a decimal library.

Comment: No, 1.0 will never be anything but 1.0.  Rounding is done in a very predictable way, and any integer below 2^24 is going to be perfectly exact every single time.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I wrote that 1.0 is fictional example.

Comment: It would be easy enough to pick 0.1, or 1/3, or 100000001.  There are lots of non-fictional examples.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It would be easy enough for you to edit my answer. Do you like it now? (1/3 is not representable in decimal either, so it's not useful example)